.Net string equality comparer class that works exactly as SQL collation
I need to implement import function in a table with a string column that have a unique index. To access database I'm using EF Core 8. To make sure import will run smoothly I'm removing all duplicates in C# code, but still import is failing.
I have digged around and found a comparer that should match behaviour of SQL server: CollationInfo.GetCollationInfo("Latin1_General_CI_AS").EqualityComparer from Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects package. But still when I'm comparing:
  CollationInfo.GetCollationInfo("Latin1_General_CI_AS").EqualityComparer.Equals("ß","SS")

I'm getting false while trying to import this strings into database will fail because of Unique constraint.
Database is created via EF code first. I'm calling modelBuilder.UseCollation("Latin1_General_CI_AS"); to make sure same collation is used, and when I check the unique index it has this collation set (as well as DB default collation).
Is there any EqualityComparer that matches SQL collation exactly?

I have tried your code and the comparer returned true for Equals("ß","SS")

@TimSchmelter the result depends on you OS as well as the app's target framework.

The real probem is that EF is used as an ETL tool. ORMs are NOT ETL tools, so you're already using the wrong (and very slow) tool for the job. There are no objects in ETL, so there's no point in using an ORM. A typical data import job involves importing data into a staging table, cleaning it up and then moving it to the target table. SQL Server already has its own very fast ETL system, SSIS

Since you are using EF8, your target framework must be .NET 8. Accordingly to this question, .NET 5 introduced a breaking change in string comparison algorithm and you are using the newer version of it (ICU-based).
Even that ß and ss are considered equal because ß is used only in German language, .NET with ICU handles ß and ss comparison differently (Github issue for .NET runtime with very detailed explanation). Frankly speaking, I don't fully understand this explanation but I guess there was a good reason why it is like it is.
In my case a .NET 6 app running on latest Windows 10 will return false for every comparison:
var k1 = StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("en-US", false), CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreWidth | CompareOptions.IgnoreKanaType).Equals("ß", "SS"); 
var k2 = StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("de-DE", false), CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreWidth | CompareOptions.IgnoreKanaType).Equals("ß", "SS"); 
var k21 = StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("de-AT", false), CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreWidth | CompareOptions.IgnoreKanaType).Equals("ß", "SS");

unless I add CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace as recommended.
Your .NET code doesn't work because CollationInfo.GetCollationInfo("Latin1_General_CI_AS") returns a comparer that was created without this new CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace workaround (BTW, you are using an older version of the package, right? try to update to latest v170+).
Now back to MS SQL Server. I couldn't find an explanation of how SQL Server's string comparison works under the hood but I assume it has to either use OS's functions to be most performant, or to mimic default Windows behavior (i.e., old NLS-based) as much as they can to deliver same consistent results even when OS is upgraded. Either way it works differently than latest .NET implementation.
UPDATE 1:
IMPORTANT: I made a mistake in previous version of this update. By accident I used tempdb to run execute the scripts below instead of switching to a newly created database with correct collation. That's why I removed the scripts and directly asked the developers about this weird behavior
For testing I used Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects v150.18208 on .NET 6 / latest Win 10.
CollationInfo.GetCollationInfo("Latin1_General_CI_AS") (AS - accent-sensitive) creates an equality comparer with the following flags IgnoreCase | IgnoreKanaType | IgnoreWidth
CollationInfo.GetCollationInfo("Latin1_General_CI_AI") (AS - accent-insensitive) creates an equality comparer with the following flags IgnoreCase | IgnoreNonSpace | IgnoreKanaType | IgnoreWidth.
Same behavior I observe when upgraded to the latest version of Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser (172.0.1).
GSerg in the comment below was asking what is the purpose of CollationInfo.GetCollationInfo method if it doesn't return an equality comparer that works same like MS SQL Server. Since I am not a developer of the above mentioned packages, I can only assume that the current behavior was kept either because of the backwards compatibility, or they assume that NLS is still widely used (there ß and ss are equal), or because adding IgnoreNonSpace will make _AS and _AI look same which makes no sense, or they forgot to update the package.

It doesn't seem that the general discussion about the ICU changes in .NET 5 is relevant. If GetCollationInfo is supposed to return a string comparer that works like SQL Server's, then this is what it should do, otherwise it's a pointless method. As for SQL Server, it has both SQL Server collations and Windows collations.

Thank you Volodymyr for your reply. All your assumprions were correct. After updating SMO to latest version the code stopped to work. CollationInfo doesn't have property that returns Comparer any more. And you are right, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace will make "ß" and "ss" equal. But i'm still not sure which culture I need to specify in order to match SQL server behaviour.

@GSerg Actually the method works as intended, just not in this case :) I added an update to answer your comment and explain why I think that current approach is not completely wrong. About the SQL Server collation: I know that it has both options but the question is how they work under the hood. Logically Windows collation is bound to OS but this sentence from SQL collation chapter However, sorting Unicode data is compatible with a particular version of Windows sorting rules can mean both: "we mimic windows rules to compare strings" and "we use windows OS funtions to compare strings"

@OlegOshkoderov I updated my answer with an explanation why I think package developers kept this behavior. If I am correct then you have just two options: either create/update an equality comparer manually or try to switch to Latin1_General_CI_AI.

The "Windows" collation behaviour is fixed and so won't change if there are changes to the OS behaviour. Which is why there is also a later collation available Latin1_General_100_CI_AS to get a later cut of the Windows collation rules

@GSerg I created a bug on Github. Hopefully someone can take a look and explan us why this behavior was not fixed.

I was using StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("en-US", false),         CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreWidth | CompareOptions.IgnoreKanaType | CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) and it was working fine. Untill now when I got a string containint dotless 'i' character U+0131 that is in SQL equal to 'i' (U+0096) but it's not equal in .Net. So now I'm back to original question: How can I get exact comparer that matches SQL behaviour?
